# the boundary homomorphism $[\Sigma S^{n-1},X]\to[S^n,X]$ is identity?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Given a Puppe sequence $\cdots \to S^{n-1} \to Y \to S^n(\simeq Y/S^{n-1}) \to \Sigma S^{n-1} \to \cdots$, where $Y=S^{n-1}\cup_{2\iota} e^n$ where $\iota:S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$ is identity,

we have a long exact sequence

$$\cdots \to [\Sigma S^{n-1},X] \to [S^n,X] \to [Y,X]\to [S^{n-1},X]\to\cdots.$$

Then boundary homomorphism $[\Sigma S^{n-1},X]\to[S^n,X]$ is identity? Or trivial?

Comment: Depends on what $Y$ is.  For example, it could be $S^{n-1} \vee S^n$ or it could be $D^n$.

Comment: $Y=S^{n-1}\cup_{2\iota} e^n$ where $\iota:S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$ is identity.

Comment: Then the boundary homomorphism is neither the identity nor trivial.

Comment: How check that?

Comment: Check that you can get the same Puppe sequence from $S^{n-1} \stackrel{2\iota}{\to} S^{n-1} \to Y$, and so the boundary map is really determined by this attaching map.